# Community user impersonation - Single signon

Tags: community, oauth

we have a community portal setup and we have a third  application running which uses this communication portal for single signon. That is for end users ..they login to third party application by using this community portal for single signon
Now the issue is.. a salesforce user is logging into portal (with impersonation).. They are able to login to portal. But now when they try to login to custom thirdparty application when the third party application redirects user back to salesforce for oauth check, salesforce displays the error message as

> "Insufficient Privileges You do not have the level of access necessary
>   to perform the operation you requested. Please contact the owner of
>   the record or your administrator if access is necessary. For more
>   information, see Insufficient Privileges Errors."

Any help on this is much appreciated.